# Meteor websocket connection failed using apache

Tags: apache-http-server, node.js, virtual-host, websocket, meteor

I deployed a Meteor app to a DO Droplet using MeteorUp. I configured apache's Virtual Hosts for this website like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName filipe-garcia.com
    ServerAlias www.filipe-garcia.com

    ServerAdmin me@filipe-garcia.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/sockjs/           [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /sockjs/ ws://localhost:3000/$1     [P,L]

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

But I'm still getting a

> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://filipe-garcia.com/sockjs/622/9hwpvs81/websocket' failed: Error
>   during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

error on my console.
I have googled this and found a multitude of solutions (mostly variations of this same VHosts), without success on any.

Everything else seems to be working perfectly, except for this error (which I have not yet felt anything because of it, because this app is not relying on websockets yet).

I'm not sure how I should fix this. I'm running Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 32bits and I have proxy, proxy_connect, proxy_http, proxy_wstunnel enabled.

**EDIT**: It must have something to do with the way the proxy is configured, because if I point my browser to the machine and port it is running on directly, this error does not happen.

As a **tiny bonus question**, by using a nodejs server, should I remove the DocumentRoot line of the file or just leave it there?

Thank you.

Comment: I've same same issue, Can you please tell me how did you solve it ? plsss

Answer (score 0):

For me.. simply adding the following to ..sites-enabled..(ubuntu+apache) worked for me:

```
ProxyRequests off
   <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   <Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
   </Location>
```

Make sure you add to sites-enabled not sites-available

Comment: Hmm.. tried that... Doesn't work :S
BTW, it is on sites-enabled indeed... So, not that..